# How do I add attributes to properties generated by Linq2Sql in a different partial class

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Let's say I've a partial class generated by Linq2Sql.Let's say the generated class has 2 properties **LastName** and **FirstName**. How do I add attributes to its properties using an other partial class?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [metadata buddy classes](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2010/01/28/separating-metadata-classes-from-model-classes-in-dataannotations-using-custom.aspx)

Ex:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(MyClassMetadata)]
public partial class MyClass
{
    public class MyClassMetadata
    {
         [StringLength(30)]
         public string FirstName {get;set;}

         [StringLength(30)]
         [Required]
         public string LastName {get;set;}    
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that all it's there to do? Nice! But what's MyClassMetadata?

Comment: @Richard77 : MyClassMetadata is the buddy class (see in the example) that is only the replication of the properties of your main class in order to  assignate data annotation attributes

Comment: Should perhaps mention that this is specific to Linq-to-SQL; you can’t use this to add custom attribute to any field/property in any partial class.